# Calling a returned integer to all other methods

Tags: java

I'm very new (And admitedly terrible) at java, and have a class assignment where you're taking a veriable size to scale an ascii image of the Seattle Space Needle.
The Finished product is supposed to look like this:
http://www.garfieldcs.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/Garfield-HS-AP-CS-space-needle-expected_output.txt

So, an issue I'm having is that you're supposed to be using mainly Nested For loops and Multiple Methods. Namely, I cannot get the same integer (*SIZE*) to be recognized by all methods.
Currently This is what I have:

```
public static int SizeQuestion(int SIZE) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the size.");
SIZE = sc.nextInt();
return SIZE; }
```

So hopefully I would be able to call *SIZE* from any method, assuming I invoke **SizeQuestion** first. But, I'm not sure I'm getting this to work right. The next part of the code includes some of the nested for loops I mentioned, but I can't be sure if it's actually using the *SIZE* variable.

```
public static void ziggurat(int SIZE) {
for(int line = 1; line <= SIZE; line++) {

    for(int i = 1; i <= (SIZE - line) * 4; i++) {
System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.print("   ");

for(int i = 1;i <= (line - 1) * 4; i++) {
    System.out.print(" ");}
    System.out.println("||");}

for(int line = 1; line <= SIZE; line++) {

for(int i = 1; i <= (SIZE - line) * 4; i++) {
System.out.print(" ");}
System.out.print("___/");

for(int i = 1;i <= (line - 1) * 4; i++) {
System.out.print(":");}
System.out.print("||");

for(int i = 1; i <= (line - 1) * 4; i++) {
System.out.print(":");}
System.out.print("\\___");

System.out.println();}
```

Sorry if the formatting is a bit messy, java code does not like being Copy-Pasted.

The problem is, The 'easy' part of the code, calling the methods doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String []args) {
SizeQuestion();
ziggurat(); 
}
```

Eclipse gives me an error saying:

> The The method SizeQuestion(int) in the type Project1 is not applicable for the arguments ()

I'd really love to have someone answer this, as this assignment is already late and honestly I cannot get any peace of mind since all my resources don't go over method calling and returning.

Answer (score 0):

First thing : You are passing an argument in method `SizeQuestion` which is not necessary. Because SizeQuestion don't need any arguement to execute its code. So change that loop like below :

```
public static int SizeQuestion()
```

And change your main method to this :

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    ziggurat(SizeQuestion()); 
}
```

What it does : `SizeQuestion()` method will take the size of question from user and pass it to `ziggurat` method.

Answer (score 0):

A method should take arguments only when it needs to do something with it. In your case, `SizeQuestion` takes an integer argument and does nothing with it. The only thing this method needs to do is to return a user input value. So, you can just modify your SizeQuestion method and remove the int argument from it.

```
public static int SizeQuestion() {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the size.");
int size= sc.nextInt();
return size; 
}
```

Your main method will look like this:

```
public static void main(String []args) {
int size = SizeQuestion();
ziggurat(size); 
}
```

Comment: I believe this one will work. Thanks you, as well as everyone who answered!

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the required parameter 
e.g.

```
public static void main(String []args) {
  SizeQuestion(1);
  ziggurat(1); 
}
```

You can define the SIZE variable as class variable or instance variable to solve your problem.
e.g.

```
public class CalculateSize{
        public static int SIZE = 0;

          public static int SizeQuestion() {

          Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Please enter the size.");
          SIZE = sc.nextInt();
          return SIZE; 
        }

       public static void ziggurat() {
        for(int line = 1; line <= SIZE; line++) {

        for(int i = 1; i <= (SIZE - line) * 4; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("   ");

        for(int i = 1;i <= (line - 1) * 4; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");}
            System.out.println("||");}

        for(int line = 1; line <= SIZE; line++) {

        for(int i = 1; i <= (SIZE - line) * 4; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");}
        System.out.print("___/");

        for(int i = 1;i <= (line - 1) * 4; i++) {
        System.out.print(":");}
        System.out.print("||");

        for(int i = 1; i <= (line - 1) * 4; i++) {
        System.out.print(":");}
        System.out.print("\\___");

        System.out.println();
       }

      public static void main(String []args) {
      SizeQuestion();
      ziggurat(); 
      }

    }
```

Comment: There is no need to pass arguements. You should have shown a better way.